# Rails I18n default_locale and fallbacks by user preference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Rails internationalization has a nice fallback feature where empty linguistic versions don't show empty content, but a default locale's content via application configuration in `application.rb`

```
    config.i18n.default_locale = :en
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

By inference, fallbacks may be set to true, but if the application knows not what locale to fallback upon, then there is breakage.

For multi-user application with fallbacks, what approach must be taken to have the fallback local *not* be the config.i18n.default_locale but a user defined one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the fallback configuration from the `application.rb` by setting the `I18n.fallbacks` on the app level. For example:

```
#application_controller

before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  ......
  I18n.fallbacks = current_user.fallback_locales
end
```

That being said, on the user account page might be a field/list of fallback languages that user can choose, so every time `I18n` goes to fallback it will display it in the preselected language.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: `fallback_locales` singular  `fallback_locale` as a sensible column name, I assume.  Neat.